# Can I rehydrate fish in sugary mixture?

Tags: sugar, fish

I have some dried stock fish, and I want to rehydrate it in a mixture of jaggery and water for a dessert taco. Can that be done? I don't want to waste the fish trying this out. Like, is a mixture like that too thick to be absorbed? Or can I find a nice ratio of  jaggery and water where I can have sweet but still umami fish?

Comment: Chef Saito on NHK’s Dining with the Chef once said when poaching to add sugar first and then wait before adding salt, because the salt would prevent the sugar from being absorbed.  As they salt is already in there, you might not get much sugar uptake.  But if that’s the case, you might be able to make a caramel and give the fish a sweet coating.

Answer (score 6):

Well, that's an interesting combination. I wish you joy of it.

It'll be difficult to significantly sweeten the stockfish while simultaneously rehydrating it; a saturated sugar solution will take days or weeks and the fish may rot by the time you're done, and a weak sugar solution won't sweeten the fish. Instead I think you're best off rehydrating it as normal and then boiling it in a thick jaggery syrup afterwards.

Incidentally, I'm put in mind of [Korean preparations of dried anchovies](https://www.koreanbapsang.com/myulchi-bokkeum-stir-fried-anchovies/). Might be worth adapting, or at least looking for inspiration there.

Comment: Thank you! I thought it would be rather difficult or unavisable, but your link is very helpful for this!

Answer (score 4):

As a note - From a biological perspective for water to diffuse into a tissue like your salt fish there needs to be more water present than salt (essentially). This is something called [osmosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osmosis), where water moves passively across a semi-permeable membrane (cell membranes in the tissue in this case). In living things (I don't know about dead dried tissues like stock fish), this works best with a slightly salty solution. This is the same principle that sports drinks work on and the use of crystalloid saline solutions in medicine.

In practical terms, this means that if the water concentration in your sugar solution is lower than the water content in your stock fish you won't get any movement of the water into the fish. Now this is quite unlikely to be the case as there isn't much water in dried fish, but it does mean that the rehydration process will take longer than it would in water or a slightly salty solution.

Personally, in terms of rehydration then sweetening, you might be better off hydrating then packing in a sugar coating, similar to what is sometimes done when smoking salmon. Or even better, get some fresh fish and work from there with the sugar. However, I think you are in uncharted territory here

It should be noted I read stock fish and assumed salted dried fish rather than air-dried, but the above still applies. I don't know what you are particularly aiming at with the taco, but there are plenty of other sources of umami that might work better - perhaps miso and caramel or something similar.